# How to fetch javascript function in swift UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, uiwebview

I use UIWebView to show simple web. This web fire javaScript functions and I must to know when they was firing. 
My question: How I can fetch javaSctipt in swift code using UIWebView?

Comment: You can do this using a `WKWebView` and implementing the `WKScriptMessageHandler` protocol. You can read about the differences between `UIWebView` and `WKWebView` here: http://nshipster.com/wkwebkit/

Answer (score 0):

As beyowulf mentioned, you can do this with WKWebView. If you need to use UIWebView, here's one option... This lets you define a function that is bound to javascript's console.log()

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {   
    let logFunction: @convention(block) (String) -> Void = { (msg: String) in
        print("JS Console: \(msg)")
    }

    let context = webView.valueForKeyPath("documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext") as! JSContext
    context.objectForKeyedSubscript("console").setObject(unsafeBitCast(logFunction, AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "log")
}
```